# rspec test for passing params into a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am having trouble setting up a spec for something that I did. I know that it is working the way I want it to because i've manually tested this, but I know if I still want a spec associated with it.

I have an index of players, and I also have a section of teams that are able to assign priority players. By doing that assigning, they pulling from the initial controller that generates the index.

For the team section I have just an ajax call where I am passing the params

```
ajax:
  url: "#{admin_players_path(disabled: 'false')}"
  dataType: 'json'
```

Here is the controller, I have a conditional in there that accounts for the request from the team page.

```
 def index
    @q = @player.search(params[:q])

    if params[:disabled] == 'false'
      @player = @q.result(distinct: true).enabled
    else
      @player = @q.result(distinct: true)
    end
  end
```

That is essentially all I did on my app side of things, and it works well.  If I ask for the players in the normal index, it shows them to me both disabled and enabled, and if I look to assign priority players it only shows me enabled players.

My problem is revolved around my spec as I can't get things properly set up to account for that params change.

```
context "with a prioritized player set up" do
  let(:params) { { disabled: false } }

  let!(:player1) { create(:player, disabled: true, disabled_at: Time.current) }
  let!(:player2) { create(:player) }

  it 'returns only enabled players' do
    get :index, params: params

    expect(assigns[:player]).to_not include(player1)
  end
end
```

Regardless of how I try to setup my spec, I cannot get the proper condition the way i'd like and keep getting the spec to fail.  Would anyone know what I am missing with this one?

Comment: Are you able to post the failing spec output, since it is hard to debug without the error message the failing spec is producing?

Comment: Its a little tricky for me to do that, but I do get  `Failure/Error: expect(assigns[:players]).to_not include(player1)`   which is telling me that i'm not setting up the spec properly. Specifically what I am struggling with is testing the other side of the conditional I have in my spec.  `
    if params[:disabled] == 'false'
      @player = @q.result(distinct: true).enabled`

Definitely having trouble getting that section of my controller properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a little work behind it, I was able to figure out what was needed within this.

In the ajax url I have the params set to `disabled:  'false'`

but in the spec I have the params set at `let(:params) { { disabled: false } }`

The problem is that in the ajax call I have things set as a string, but in the spec I have them set as a boolean.

All I had to do was change the set up to `let(:params) { { disabled: ‘false' } }`

and the specs were all good to go!